# getting/changing value of html input field using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do a simple up down counter. For some reason I'm having trouble getting javascript to target the correct element. I'm currently trying to use jQuery.

here's my html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>New Web Project</title>



        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/go.js"></script>



    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr ><td ><button id="up" onclick="modCount(1)">2,3,4,5,6</button></td></tr>
            <tr><td><h1><input id="count" value="0" /></h1></td></tr>
            <tr ><td ><button id="down" onclick="modCount(-1)">10,J,Q,K,A</button></td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my go.js:

```
function modCount(val){

var CC = $("count").value;

alert($("count").value);

var NewCount = parseInt(CurrentCount,10) + val;


$("count").value = NewCount;

return NewCount;
};
```

What am i doing wrong? The alert keeps saying the value of $("count") is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have lots wrong.

```
var CC = $("count").value;
```

When targetting by id in jquery, prefix with `#`, and the method to get the value of a field is `val()`. Change to

```
var CC = $("#count").val();
```

---

```
var NewCount = parseInt(CurrentCount,10) + val;
```

You called the variable `CC` not `CurrentCount`. Change to

```
var NewCount = parseInt(CC,10) + val;
```

(Nice work providing the radix to `parseInt` - full marks there!)

---

```
$("count").value = NewCount;
```

Again, supply the hash, and the method to set a value is also `.val()`. Change to

```
$("#count").val(NewCount);
```

---

```
return NewCount;
```

There is no need to return the value, you're never using it - just remove this line.

Working sample:

```js
function modCount(val){

var CC = $("#count").val();

var NewCount = parseInt(CC,10) + val;

$("#count").val(NewCount);

};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr ><td ><button id="up" onclick="modCount(1)">2,3,4,5,6</button></td></tr>
    <tr><td><h1><input id="count" value="0" /></h1></td></tr>
    <tr ><td ><button id="down" onclick="modCount(-1)">10,J,Q,K,A</button></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$("count")
```

to

```
$("#count")
```

...i.e. you mean to target it by ID, which means prefixing the selector with `#`

With jQuery, always make your selectors your first suspect when something goes wrong. You can check if they're matching anything by running

```
alert($('your-selector-here').length);
```

If it gives `0`, the selector's wrong, or the code is running before the element is in the DOM.

Comment: ^ Yep - posted this right when I was logging in to say the same!

Comment: Not my DV, put Im guessing because you've only scratched the surface of what's wrong!

Comment: Yeah you're right. I rushed it and just saw the selector problem so I lazily assumed that was all that was wrong (if often is.)